# CakePHP, CakeEmail, send attachment without a file

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

[`CakeEmail`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) has a very simple API, one of the many options is `attachments`, which takes an array of paths, as it seems.

However, my system is build to create a PDF as a string - it is never saved on the system - and then send it out via e-Mail. So how can I get CakeEmail to attach a binary string as a file?

Comment: So why not just save the content to a temporary file and delete after sending?

Comment: @ADmad how would I know when it's save to delete?

Comment: After sending the email ofcourse.

Comment: @ADmad Isn't that Asynchronous?

Comment: The actual delivery of email by the transport can be but reading the file and generating the message content and sending to appropriate transport by CakeEmail isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my EmailLib which wraps the CakeEmail class and provides a possibility to write from blob (without a file so to speak):
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/EmailLib.php#L100

or extract the necessary information to write your own extension that provides what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Writing file from blob is also possible in upcoming cakePHP 2.4 - see 4.3 in the following link. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments